How to properly format an abstract in Rmarkdown - LaTeX to PDF
I have never been able to get the first section of an abstract to be flush with the left side of the page in Rmarkdown. When I render the following MRE 'Premise' will be inserted about 2 tabs closer to the center than it should be. 'Methods and Results' and 'Conclusions' will both be correct.
I have played extensively with adding tabs and trying to drop the vertical bars, and quoting the abstract contents but just cannot figure out the magic combination to stop this behaviour.
--- 
title: 'A few people may read this thing'
author:  | 
    |  $^1$Research Institute    
    |  $^2$University  
    | Person$^1$^[Author for Correspondence: human@place.org], Other Person$^1$$^,$$^2$
abstract: | 
  **Premise:** We did stuff.     
  **Methods and Results:** We used and developed stuff to accomplish stuff.       
  **Conclusions:** You too can do stuff.     
keywords: |
  rmarkdown, latex, weird indent in abstract   
output:
  pdf_document: default
--- 

# Introduction



You can use the LaTeX macro \noindent to suppress the indent at the start of a paragraph.  In your Rmd document that could look like this:
--- 
title: 'A few people may read this thing'
author:  | 
    |  $^1$Research Institute    
    |  $^2$University  
    | Person$^1$^[Author for Correspondence: human@place.org], Other Person$^1$$^,$$^2$
abstract: |
  \noindent 
  **Premise:** We did stuff.     
  **Methods and Results:** We used and developed stuff to accomplish stuff.       
  **Conclusions:** You too can do stuff.     
keywords: |
  rmarkdown, latex, weird indent in abstract   
output:
  pdf_document: default
--- 

# Introduction

